# local absolute paths (C:...) for script tag

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, file-uri

Is there any way to properly reference a javascript file on disk that is not necessarily relative to the HTML file itself but to the file system of the host?

I am currently working on a **strictly local site** (always opened with file:// ...) and no web server. (only windows hosts)

This works for chrome and firefox without any issues:

```
<script src="resources/test1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="resources/test2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="file:///C:/test3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="file://localhost/C:/test4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//localhost/C:/test5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Only works in chrome:

```
<script src="file:C:/test6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="C:/test7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="C:\test8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The Internet Explorer (IE11) on the other hand does not load these files (test3.js - test8.js) without any warning or error. Is there a proper way to do that?

I also tried adding a shared folder (//localhost/data/test.js) to ensure i don't need any : for the url. Did work for firefox and chrome, but not for IE.

I am aware that this is not the intended use of script tags or even HTML sites and that 'proper' is probably not the correct term anyway.

Comment: Could you include in the question on what versions / modes of IE does this happens?

Comment: Done! Happens on IE 11

Comment: Have you tried `file://localhost/C:/`?

Comment: Also works for Chrome and FF but not for IE :(

Comment: I’d recommend you go check the settings for the security zone this is running under in IE Internet Options – there’s a lot of obscure settings, some of which might influence this behavior.

Comment: I did check all of the settings (well, most of them :)), so far, nothing changed.

Comment: Check IE dev tools and make sure you do not get Cross-Origin security block. Usually you can only access resources that are in same level or under your current file subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the alert by allowing '*active content*' option. Go to Tools ->Internet options ->Advanced -> Security ->**Allow active content to run files**

Hope this helps!